# How to use "if() and else if()" condition in Windows Batch files

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am trying to create a batch file which can create a folder in current working directory with present date. But, I wanted to print if the date is first or twenty second then I should create like "1stJan2000" or "22ndJan2000". So, I want to know how to use "IF() and ELSE IF()" in Windows batch files. Please Help me or give a solution to create folder as per my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not need `else` here. simply do `if` in 2 separate lines for different conditions. but you question is marked as unclear as you posted no code.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

He means that he want to create a folder in the current directory by the current date using batch programming for example if the date is 30/04/2018 the folder name would be **30April2018** ... now he asked that id the dates are (01,02,21,22,21)/05/2018 then the name should be **1stmay2018** instead of **1May2018** or **22ndMay2018** instead of **22May2018** or **21stMay2018** instead of **21May2018**
i hope now you all got the question

Yes you can use if statement for that you have to manually check for each date like (1,2,3,21,22,31) and then you can replace it with ur value....

foe if else you can study 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_if_else_statement.htm

http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-5-if-then-conditionals.html

i woud recomend to store the date in a variable and then check for it and store the new name in another folder